# Filter php array by column value

Tags: php, arrays, filter

I want to filter out the array with status=paid, is there any builtin PHP function for this?

```
Array
(

[0] => Array
        (

            [id] => 140
            [status] => paid

        )

[1] => Array
        (

            [id] => 140
            [status] => new

        )
[2] => Array
        (

            [id] => 140
            [status] => new

        )
)
```

Comment: You will be surprised, it's called `array_filter`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this-

```
$musawar = array_filter($arr, function ($var) {
    return ($var['status'] == 'paid');
});
```

Another way is -

```
function my_filter($elt) {
    return $elt['status'] == 'paid';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$filtered = array_filter($raw, function($element) {
   return $element['status'] === 'paid';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a function like this :

```
array_filter($yourArray, "statusPaid")
```

Then define the callback function `statusPaid()`, to check [status]. It has only to return a check on `['status'] == 'paid'` for each element of your array

Doc [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)